# Flex gives blank page when testing

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I just started flex today.I am getting just a blank page.But if I right click on the page I can see the FlashPlayer is loaded.

Below is the test code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="500" minHeight="400" width="500" height="400" creationComplete="testFlex()">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private function testFlex():void{
                trace("WORKING!");
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:Button x="199" y="199" label="Test" id="test"/>


</s:Application>
```

I am expecting to see the button at least.

EDIT:If I open the html from the bin-debug folder then it shows?But when I test from flex it just shows a blank page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working.Had to install the debug player.

Comment: Don't forget to accept this as the solution when you get a chance.